# align an object

Tags: css

I wanted to align a newsticker about 300px above it's current position , but I am unable to do so. Please help.
The page is uploaded for viewing at http://cerebration.0fees.net/test/bottom.html

scroll down the page to find the newsticker.

The css file contains the css code for the newsticker and the newsticker is of white color(color mentioned for identification).
The html page code is at : http://pastebin.com/dP8dSEDS
and the css code is as at : http://pastebin.com/46YvqwT7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://doctype.com is more appropriate for layout questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. anyways you can use a 3 column layout.

Reference:
http://www.neuroticweb.com/recursos/3-columns-layout/

Comment: I don't need 3 column using html , I have used an image of 3 columns , so I just need to position the newsticker above 300px.